# Get value from web push notification payload

Tags: javascript, payload, web-push

I received this payload from a web push notification.

```
{
  "data": {
    "notification": "{\"icon\":\"\\/static\\/assets\\/notifications\\/loader-100x100.png\",\"vibrate\":[200,100,200,100,200,100,400],\"tag\":\"request\",\"body\":\"12:30\",\"title\":\"HELLO\",\"actions\":[{\"icon\":\"\\/static\\/assets\\/notifications\\/loader-100x100.png\",\"action\":\"https:\\/\\/example.com\\/#done\",\"title\":\"OK\"},{\"icon\":\"\\/static\\/assets\\/notifications\\/loader-100x100.png\",\"action\":\"https:\\/\\/example.com\\/#open\",\"title\":\"Edit\"}]}"
  },
  "collapse_key": "do_not_collapse",
  "from": "1111111"
}
```

How to get the value of **title**?
I tried this without luck:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(payload);
const notificationTitle = parsed["notification"]["title"];
```

Comment: looks like it would be `parsed['data']["notification"]["title"];` (or `parsed.data.notification.title`)

Comment: actually.. looks like you need to parse notification separately..

Comment: yes, notification is a valid JSON key, what you need to parse is the content of notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that object just do

```
var parsedNotification = JSON.parse(payload.data.notification);
var title = parsedNotification.title;
console.log(title);
```